# $g = -e^{-f(x,y)}$ is concave if we know that $f(x,y) = 2x+y-x^2$ is concave.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, functions

Let $f(x,y) = 2x+y-x^2$ be a two variable function.

(a) Show that $f$ is concave.

(b) Show that $g = -e^{-f(x,y)}$ is concave.

---

I have proved part (a) using Hessian matrix.

We have $f_x = 2-2x$ and $f_y = 1$.

Then we can compute: $f_{xx} = -2, f_{xy} = 0, f_{yy} = 0$.

Hence the Hessian matrix is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $-2,0$.

Thus it is negative semi-definite.

And $f$ is concave.

---

But I am stuck with (b). Need some help.

I have tried to find the Hessian matrix, but the entries are coming very complicated. Is there any other method?

Comment: user5210, if you add to your question how you proved the first part and what you tried to prove the second part, we will help you, otherwise your question will be closed by moderators very soon.

Comment: @Angelo I have added the proof for (a).

Comment: user5210, you should also add your attempts and efforts in order to solve the second part if you want us to help you.

Comment: @Angelo I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: user5210, I have written a complete answer. Read it and let me know if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem :**

If $\;\varphi:A\to\Bbb R\;$ and $\;\psi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;$ are two convex functions (where $A$ is a convex set of $\,\Bbb R^n$) and the function $\;\psi\;$ is monotonically non-decreasing$\,,\;$ then also the function $\;\psi\!\circ\!\varphi:A\to\Bbb R\;$ is convex.

**Proof :**

We will prove that for any $\,x,y\in A\,$ and for any $\,t\in[0,1]\,,\,$ it results that $\;(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)\big((1-t)x+ty\big)\leqslant (1-t)(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)(x)+t(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)(y)\,.$

For any $\,x,y\in A\,$ and for any $\,t\in[0,1]\,,\,$ we get that
\begin{align}
(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)\big((1-t)x+ty\big)&=\psi\left[\varphi\big((1-t)x+ty\big)\right]\\[3pt]
&\leqslant\psi\big((1-t)\varphi(x)+t\varphi(y)\big)&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\color{brown}{\text{( }\varphi\text{ is convex and }\psi\text{ is non-decreasing )}}\\[3pt]
&\leqslant(1-t)\psi(\varphi(x))+t\psi(\varphi(y))\quad\color{brown}{\text{( }\psi\text{ is convex )}}\\[3pt]
&=(1-t)(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)(x)+t(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)(y)\,.
\end{align}

---

Since the function $\;f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R\;$ is concave, it follows that the function $\;\varphi=-f\;$ is convex.

Moreover, the function $\;\psi(x)=e^x:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;$ is convex and non-decreasing ( in fact is increasing ), so we can apply the previous Theorem and get that

the function $\;\psi\!\circ\!\varphi=e^{-f}:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R\;$ is convex ,

consequently ,

the function $\,g=-e^{-f}\,$ is concave.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to calculate the Hessian for part b). What you need are the following three facts:

1. The function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(z) =
           e^z$ is convex.
2. A function $g$ is concave (*convex*) if $\ -g \ $  is convex
   (*concave*).
3. The composition of two convex functions is convex.

Now since your function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is concave then $-f$ is convex then its composition with $e^z$ which is $e^{-f}$ is convex then $g= - e^{-f}$ is concave.

**EDIT:** As Angelo pointed out in the comments, fact 3 is not right. The correct fact should be

3*. If two functions $u$ and $v$ are convex and $u$ is non-decreasing then the composition $u(v(x))$ is convex.

Comment: Tarek, the composition of two convex functions is not necessarily convex in general, for example $\varphi(x)=x^2-1$ and $\psi(x)=x^2$ are convex but $(\psi\!\circ\!\varphi)(x)=x^4-2x^2+1$ is not convex.

Comment: Tarek, it is necessary to add another hypothesis to the function $\psi$ in order that the composition $\psi\!\circ\!\varphi$ is convex, in fact it is not convex in general.

Comment: @Angelo, thank you for pointing this out. I will amend my answer.